# When I click a custom menu link, how do I make it update the URL in the browser to the external link?

Tags: menus, urls

I have created a "custom link" under Menus. 
[image]
The problem is that URL in the browser retains the Wordpress URL ( http://blog.tabsonrahm.org ) instead of the linked URL ( http://tabsonrahm.org/about ).

When I click a custom menu link, how do I make it update the URL in the browser to the external link? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you're using a frame. The url is changing within the frame itself but it can't reflect it to the base site. You'll have to remove the frame from the site in order to have the url change for you. In fact, I really don't see why you have a frame anyway because if I right click (using FF) and select view only this frame...the site works exactly the same and the URL changes.

Unless I'm missing something, I believe that's your fix. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: jared, thanks a lot for your response. I look through all my Wordpress settings and theme settings. How exactly do I remove the frame? If you go directly to http://blog.tabsonrahm.org and click on the first blog article link, it can be reproduced.

Comment: The frame is built into the code itself. It's nothing you can remove with a setting in WP. Did you build the site or someone else? Basically the frame is wrapping your whole site and from what I can tell, there's no reason to do that. If you built it, try removing that frame wrapper. If someone else built it, you might ask them if they can make that modification for you.